# Interpreting TensorFlow playground simple neural network

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow

[image]

The hidden layer neuron output images are meaningful to me. But I don't understand how the model can output any number except zero for the III quadrant when all hidden layer neurons output 0 for any point in the III quadrant. I have read the TensorFlow playground documentation, but I didn't find anything helpful. I came up with a thought about the output being mapped with the sigmoid function, but I am unsure about it.

Comment: they are probably hiding the bias